# Ubuntu 14.04 cpputest examples build fail

Tags: ubuntu, build, cpputest

I installed cpputest on Ubuntu by:

```
sudo apt-get install cpputest
```

Now I am trying to build the examples from the book and it fails:

```
augre@ubuntu:~/tddec-code$ make
make -i -C code
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code'
make -f MakefileCppUTest.mk
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code'
MakefileCppUTest.mk:60: /build/MakefileWorker.mk: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/build/MakefileWorker.mk'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code'
make[1]: [all] Error 2 (ignored)
make -f MakefileUnity.mk
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code'
Running BookCode_Unity_tests
Unity test run 1 of 1
..........!............................................................
-----------------------
71 Tests 0 Failures 1 Ignored
OK
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code'
make -i -C code-t0
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code-t0'
Makefile:42: /build/MakefileWorker.mk: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/build/MakefileWorker.mk'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/augre/tddec-code/code-t0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems like it cannot find where apt-get installed cpputest.

How can I figure that out and point it there?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find the file MakefileWorker.mk in the directories that

```
sudo apt-get install cpputest
```

created.

So decided to remove the files

```
apt-get remove cpputest
```

Then download the source:

```
cd /home/augre/bin
git clone git://github.com/cpputest/cpputest.git
```

then:

```
$ cd cpputest_build
$ autoreconf .. -i
$ ../configure
$ make
```

Then set the environment variable

```
export CPPUTEST_HOME=/home/augre/bin/cpputest
```

Then to fix one more build error:

```
cp /home/augre/bin/cpputest/cpputest_build/lib/* /home/augre/bin/cpputest/lib/
```